# We were dancing a few hours. or We were dancing for a few hours

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why? Or maybe both are correct?

> We were dancing a few hours.

or

> We were dancing for a few hours.

Answer (score 4):

> We were dancing for a few hours.

This version is grammatically correct: the preposition **for** is required to attach the additional information about how long you were dancing.

> We were dancing a few hours

You may hear this version on its own in informal speech. It is more likely to be used when you want to explain **when** something happened, and want to emphasise the **when** rather than the **how long**: for example:

> We were dancing a few hours before my ankle finally gave way
>
> [I was only gone five minutes](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3627037/I-gone-five-minutes-Humorous-video-shows-excitable-dog-howling-like-SEAGULL-return-owner.html)